# Всплывающие подсказки VS Code на русском?

Tags: visual-studio-code

я хотел бы сделать всплывающие подсказки на русском языке, поэтому ищу файл, который содержит текст об этих подсказках, чтобы перевести их. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где находится файл в папке? Или может уже есть какое-то готовое расширение для автоматического перевода всплывающих подсказок?
(Речь именно о всплывающих подсказках при наведении мыши, как на скриншоте.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Какая сейчас локализация стоит?

Comment: Локализация стоит русская, но когда навожу мышь на теги, подсказки всплывают на английском.
UPD: Добавил еще один скриншот.

Comment: это библиотека делает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На гитхабе в разделе `issues` была данная тема. Закрыли с комментарием, что не планируют добавлять данный функционал в обозримом будущем.

На английском полная цитата (формальная)

> We closed this issue because we don't plan to address it in the foreseeable future. You can find more detailed information about our decision-making process here. If you disagree and feel that this issue is crucial: We are happy to listen and to reconsider.
> If you wonder what we are up to, please see our roadmap and issue reporting guidelines.
> Thanks for your understanding and happy coding!

Полностью ветку можно прочесть [здесь](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107511).

То что касается ручной кастомизации, то я не вижу ограничений для составления самописного расширения для данного функционала. А саму доку тащить с того же `MDN`, там есть на русском

Comment: Понятно, спасибо за ответ. Но у меня не хватит навыков написать расширение самому, а всплывающие подсказки работают даже без интернета, то есть, он берет их с какого-то файла, а не с сайте, поэтому хотелось бы просто найти этот файл и перевести его.

Comment: @Loness все немного сложнее, для примера я вам отправлю обзор на английском, как работает vscode для html. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/embedded-languages#language-services Просто переведите в гугле, прочитайте - как это работает.